# Sums of normal CDF's

Tags: probability, convolution

This is my following problem:

$$
CDF_A:F_A(x)=\Phi(x)^2
$$
$$
CDF_B:F_B(x)=1-\Phi(-x)^3
$$
$$
Defining:
X=A+(-B)
$$
I have those two CDF's and I want to calculate the probability that X is smaller than some positive value:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X\le\mu) ; 0\le\mu
$$
I know I have to use the convolution integral, but I don't know how to start doing it. 
*no need a closed form(don't think there is one) , I'm intending to calculate it numerically.
thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are independent,
$$
P(X\leqslant x)=P(A\leqslant B+x)=E(F_A(B+x))=\int_\mathbb Rf_B(t)F_A(x+t)\mathrm dt,
$$
where $F_A$ is the CDF of $A$ and $f_B$ is the PDF of $B$, thus,
$$
P(X\leqslant x)=\int_\mathbb R 3\varphi(t)\Phi(-t)^2\Phi(x+t)^2\mathrm dt.
$$
If this can help, note that
$$
X=\max(Z_1,Z_2)+\max(Z_3,Z_4,Z_5),
$$
where the random variables $Z_n$ are i.i.d. standard normal.

Comment: $$
\begin{aligned}
1.A:\mathbb{P}(\max{(w_1,w_2)\le x}) = \mathbb{P}(w_1\le x\cap w_2\le x)\\
&=\mathbb{P}(w_1\le x)\mathbb{P}(w_2 \le x)\\
&=\Phi(x)^2\\
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
2.B:\mathbb{P}(\min{(w_3,w_4,w_5)}\le x)
&=1-\mathbb{P}(\min{(w_3,w_4,w_5)} \ge x)\\
&=1-\mathbb{P}(\max{(-w_3,-w_4,-w_5)}\le -x)\\
&=1-\Phi(-x)^3\\
\text{so }  X=A+(-B)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(X\le \mu)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: 1. are the integral limits is between -infinity to mu (i want to find the probability that X is smaller than specific value -mu-)? 2. which rule is explained your first line ?

Comment: The "integral limits" are what is written in my answer, that is, both integrals are on the whole real line.

Comment: then where is the calculation of the probability that X is less than mu ?

Comment: ?? Try to put $x=\mu$ in the equations and see the miracle operate...

Comment: amazingly it works !!! :) for every n,k comparison -> max(w1,..,wk)-min(w_k+1,..w_n). thank you very much!

Comment: can you share a reference for the first line, how did you got the exception and from there the integral ?

Comment: Exception?? Reference: I don't know, depends on your favorite probability textbook.

Comment: $$P(A\le B+x)=E(F_A(B+x))$$ ? that what i meant, but o.k i look for it, in the text. again, thanks.

Comment: sorry I meant Expectation...